# How is the vendor sell value of an item calculated

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to know the exact mechanics/tables behind the vendor sell value calculation.
Obviously higher ilvl and higher stats equates to higher sell value.

For clarification: I'm asking the price the vendors buy the items from you for (The value amount in the bottom left corner of an item)

Comment: Are you asking about the prices set by vendors; or what they pay when you sell stuff to them?

Comment: I'm asking what they pay when you sell to them.